# Does "$x$ tends to $0$" mean "$x$ is infinitesimal"?

Tags: calculus, limits

The following notation means, as $x$ approaches $a$, the value of the function $f$, denoted $f(x)$, approaches $L$.

$$
\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L
$$

I've seen many smart people saying, the above notation means "$x$ is so close to $a$, so that $\lvert x-a \rvert$ is smaller than any positive number". I don't think this is an accurate interpretation, since it essentially uses infinitesimals in the usual settings of the real-number system. The concept of limit was invented to avoid the use of infinitesimals. So, this is certainly not accurate.

But, if the above interpretation is wrong, then what does $x \to a$ mean? I think of it not as some value, but as a process. Since $x$ is a variable, we can assign values to it. So, $x \to a$ would mean, "**for increasingly closer-to-a choices of $\mathbf x$...**" In other words, $x \to a$ doesn't say anything about the value of $x$.

So, $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ would mean, "as $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $L$."

Is this interpretation of mine accurate?

Comment: Well, there's a reason there is a formal definition of a limit, see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function).  Vague and imprecise notions don't help much.

Comment: To illustrate an obvious problem with your informal definition, consider $\lim_{x\to 0}|x|$.  as $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$, it is perfectly true that $|x|$ gets closer and closer to $-42$, yet one would not declare the limit to be $-42$.

Comment: @lulu, interesting... Haven’t thought of that before.

Comment: Indeed modern limits effectively simulate informal notions of infitesimals without actually invoking them. There are formal theories of infinitesimals (e.g; [Dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number), or [Hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)) which can define limits as evaluating at infitesimal values, but they are nonstandard.